# SQL - select the id from an avg

Tags: java, sql, database, hsqldb

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Rating
(
    rid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    mid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(movieId) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    uid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    rating INTEGER NOT NULL, 
);
```

I want to select the mid with most average rating:

```
select avg(r.rating) from rating r
```

witch returns the average. I want to return the mid`s with the most average rating. Any ideas how to do that?

**> UPDATE**

the other two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    passwordhash VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    fullname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    birthday DATE NOT NULL,
    joindate DATE NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    picturepath VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    favouritemovie VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    favouritecategory INTEGER REFERENCES category(id),
    isDeleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Movie
(
    movieId INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    moviePath VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: What do you mean "However I do not get the mid back?" ? Get it in your  Java code ?

Comment: Um. Average is an **aggregate** function. It is the result of an operation on a bunch of rows, so a bunch of `mid`s are involved - how exactly is the database supposed to know which one you want?

Comment: Additionally, the returned average is probably not a value you'll find in the `rating` column.

Comment: I want to write a query witch returns the mids with the most average rating

Comment: You can write a query around it making it as a sub-query. But their might not be any row with exactly average rating.

Comment: @maximus - Do you mean the `mid` that has the rating closest to the average one?

Comment: @Oded yes! I mean the mid that has the rating closest to the average one

Comment: I think, there are several rows with the same mid value. The OP probably wants the mid where the avarage of its ratings is maximum.

Comment: @Henry - You mean the most common rating?

Comment: @Oded no, calculate average rating for each mid (with a GROUP BY mid), then choose maximum and return the mid.

Comment: @Henry pls write a specific answer, so that I could propably accept it!

Comment: @maximus Call me visual but some sample data and expected output would have helped alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments:

> *calculate average rating for each mid (with a GROUP BY mid), then choose maximum and return the mid*

So first step, calculate average for each mid:

```
select mid, 
       avg(rating) as avg_rating
from rating
group by mid;
```

Now choose the maximum:

```
select max(avg_rating)
from (
  select avg(rating) as avg_rating
  from rating
  group by mid
) as mar
```

Now combine these:

```
select ar.mid, mar.max_avg
from (
    select mid, 
           avg(rating) as avg_rating
    from rating
    group by mid
  ) as ar
  join (
    select max(avg_rating) as max_avg
    from (
      select avg(rating) as avg_rating
      from rating
      group by mid
    ) as t
  ) as mar
  on ar.avg_rating = mar.max_avg;
```

SQLFiddle example (using Postgres, but works with HSQLDB as well): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e208a/8

It's not the most simple solution but quering on grouped data never is. Using the `TOP` construct as shown by Luther is going to be much faster. The only drawback with the `TOP 1` is that you won't notice if two movies have the same average rating.

**Edit**: Just to expand a little bit beyond HSQLDB. In a database that supports window functions (PostgreSQL, Oracle and many others), this type of question is very easy:

```
select *
from (
  select mid, 
         avg(rating) as avg_rating,
         dense_rank() over (order by avg(rating) desc) as rnk
  from rating
  group by mid
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

It is especially easy to find the second highest, third highest and so on (`where rnk = 2`, `where rnk = 3`) which is really complicated using those nested queries - but a lit bit easier when using the `TOP/LIMIT` aproach.

Comment: Hey, really much thx for your answer. However I have a huge problem with the join with the movie table because I get the avg rating back but do not know how to properly join it with the movie table. I really would appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used row_num earlier and gave up thinking of dese rank.. nice one..

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10
  mid,
  avg(cast(r.rating as float))
FROM Rating r
GROUP BY mid
ORDER BY avg(cast(r.rating as float)) DESC
```

You don't need to change the rating to a float, but I figured if you have rating of 4 anf 5 you might want the average to be 4.5 instead of just rounding to an int.

Comment: Should be `TOP 1` not `TOP 10`. Much shorter than my solution (which would work with DBMS not supporting TOP or similar constructs)

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to select mids from most aveerage rating.. try this please..

```
select max(x.avgr)
from (
  select r.mid, avg(r.rating) avgr
  from rating r
  group by r.mid
) as x;
```

or try this: works in [Sql Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a3ba/15).

```
select Top 1 r.mid, avg(r.rating) as avgr
from rating r
group by r.mid
order by avgr desc
;
```

**Those dbms where `Top` doesn't work you may use `limit 1` instead..**

```
    select r.mid, avg(r.rating) as avgr
    from rating r
    group by r.mid
    order by avgr desc Limit 1
    ;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks :) sql vs mysql... ;) I added `limit `` this seems to work. Not sure as don't have any expected results to match...against..

Comment: HSQL (the one that is used) does support `TOP` (and then there are some that don't support `LIMIT` either..) The proplem with that approach is that you don't get to see movies that have the same average rating. If that is acceptable, then using top/limit is definitely the quickest solution.